# How do I add new elements to an array if I do not know the final size when I declare it? (Resolved)

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm trying to create an app(WinForm) to send data from my server to an external server using SOAP.

I created the array

```
Friend EventArray() As GPSmodule.gps.com.module.gps.Event
Dim ReportCount as Integer=0;
```

Then inside the task I have a loop that read every line that comes from the database as result of an SQL request and format every value as requested.
After that I add the data to the current index.

```
EventArray(ReportCount).plate = Patente
EventArray(ReportCount).Evtcode = Evento
EventArray(ReportCount).date = FechaHora
EventArray(ReportCount).latitude = Latitud
EventArray(ReportCount).longitude = Longitud
EventArray(ReportCount).speed = Velocidad
EventArray(ReportCount).temperature = Sensor1
ReportCount+=1
```

But this doesn't work because EventArray has no size. How should I do it?

Comment: Create a new `List<T>` instead of an uninitialized array?

Comment: There is a method in the remote server that expect that type of array. The list could converted in to an array of type GPSmodule.gps.com.module.gps.Event?

Comment: `List<T>.ToArray()` Instance method. of course.

Comment: If you have resolved the issue yourself then you should add an answer and accept it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I didn't know that I can accept my own question, also I feel bad by doing that because many people helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing arrays is something VB.NET can do that C# can't:

```
Redim Preserve EventArray(ReportCount) '<<< add this line
EventArray(ReportCount).plate = Patente
EventArray(ReportCount).Evtcode = Evento
EventArray(ReportCount).date = FechaHora
EventArray(ReportCount).latitude = Latitud
EventArray(ReportCount).longitude = Longitud
EventArray(ReportCount).speed = Velocidad
EventArray(ReportCount).temperature = Sensor1
ReportCount+=1
```

Comment: [Array.Resize<T>()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize)

Comment: I already used Dr.Null method    List<T>.ToArray() But thanks anyway.